# Movies Poster Search API

Tags: api, search, movies

Imagine I have a list of movie titles, years which is constantly updating (every 24h or less) and I would like to get a Movie poster for every movie in the list.

I tried using this: http://mikefigueroa.com/blog/2011/08/get-first-google-image-search-result-with-php/

But the list is pretty big, and my IP is being masked as abusive.

Thanks

Comment: Is your question where to find such an API?

Comment: Yes or to make something like getting images from imdb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TheMovieDatabase's movie images API:
http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/methods/Movie.getImages

<del>**Update:**
Their new API is probably better in terms of support.
http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fmovie%2F%7Bid%7D%2Fimages</del>

**Update:**
There is a new api available: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction

Comment: I will dive into it, but I think it's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Extremely difficult API to navigate. There is a lot of broken information there. I am trying to hook up an old app I built that shows movie posters, and it was too difficult to set up that site's API. I followed their steps to get an API key and it says 404. I will find one faster by Googling "free movie poster api"